# Unable to get data from nse api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, webapi

I am trying to get option chain data from nse india, but but I am getting the following `Exception`:

```
An error occurred while sending the request.
Unable to read data from the transport connection:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Below is my code:

```
    public string getoptiondata()
            {
                var content = string.Empty;
                try
                {
                string url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY";
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
          
                using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
    
                catch(Exception   e)
                {
    
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("`enter code here`ok.txt"))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("***********  Exception *********** \n");
                        sw.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
               
                }
    
    
                return content;
            }
```

Comment: You are probably failing the TLS authetication and using TLS 1.0/1.1 as default.  You must specify TLS 1.2 (or later).  Add : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: I tried it but still getting same exception ..

Comment: Try TLS 1.3 instead of 1.2.  The website looks like it only supports 1.3.

Comment: It is not about TLS, Could you please tell me how to use proxy in .net core 2.1  because i have used proxy in  react and it working fine but don't know know how to use in .net core

Comment: AspNetCore.Proxy  is a lib but don't know  how to used it

Comment: Lets find the root cause of the issue first.  I put the URL into a webbrowser and got results.  I then went and did same and capture results in a sniffer (wireshark/fiddler).  The sniffer showed TLS 1.3.  I then ran your c# code and it did not work.  The sniffer showed TLS 1.2.

Comment: My code working on  .net 4.6 but not on .net core 2.1

Comment: it working as console app but not in controller

Comment: I do not see anything in the code that would be different between a console and a controller.  One possibility is the port is already open so you cannot open a 2nd instance of the port.  I would from cmd.exe >Netstat -a    This will give you the status of the port.  A controller usually deserializes the data, but the code posted isn't doing any deserialize.  So I woulld use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the good and bad results.  You should get a 200 OK status in the response if good and a 400/500 error is bad.  You can also check version of TLS.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line for SSl/TSL:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```